# Is there any Search engine providers for asp.net mvc site?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, search-engine

Is there any search engine providers who can enable search on custom database and can directly integrate with asp.net mvc web site/application ? Looking on google but no idea which is good(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google following:

```
elastic search ASP.NET
solr search ASP.NET
```

This will hopefully give you some options.